# Multiple Users Open Same File and Overwrite Work

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Operating System: Windows 10 Pro
When I have a file open, my coworker can open the file and does not get notified that the file is already opened or locked. He can work in the file and save, and it overwrites my version. Then when I go to save, I get notified that the file was 'modified outside of Illustrator, do I want to continue?" If you click yes, it overwrites his work and his work is lost. Is this a bug that it does not indicate that the file is already open by another user?

Answer (score 0):

Do you open the file from some kind of NAS server inside your office? Yes everyone can open such file with previlleges, and store their own respective cache. But when it comes to saving/overwrite current file it would produce such error. My solution would be saving your current work as different filename.

Maybe such feature should added by Adobe team, not only in Adobe InCopy where you can contribute to edit to one file simultaneously by different users.